# mclust plot error in eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the mclust library for R ( http://www.stat.washington.edu/mclust ) to perform EM-based GMM clustering. The mclust package runs well and I am getting my data clustered into 4 groups.

However, when I try to plot the clustering info, using the plot function:

```
plot(mod1)
```

Model-based clustering plots:

1: BIC
2: classification
3: uncertainty
4: density

Selection 1: BIC works as expected.  But I get error messages in Selections 2, 3 or 4. For example,

Selection: 2

```
Error in eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is an overflow issue, but I was able to solve the problem on my dataset by scaling it first with x <- scale(x) before calling mclust().  I don't know if that's answer-worthy, but it may help.